# Lightbox opens image in NEW WINDOW rather than inside of a lightbox

Tags: javascript, lightbox

I have tried to install lightbox, fancy box, and bootstrap. None of them work for me, and I have linked and re-linked everything. At this point, I do not know what to do. It opens up as a jpeg in a separate window, or if I add in the js before any other js, it loads way at the bottom of the page with no lightbox effects/appearance.

```
<head>
    <title>Home: Central Pacific</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="Central Pacific is a 300,000 square foot Class “A” Industrial Development in the Heart of the San Francisco Bay Area" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Real Estate, Industrial, Development, San Francisco, Bay Area, Union City" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="css/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel-layers.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#gallery a').lightBox();
});
    </script>

    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-noscript.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    </noscript>

    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v9.css" /><![endif]-->
</head>
```

And.. (without the spaces)

```
<div id="gallery"><a href="images/aerial01.jpg" rel="lightbox">See Location Map</a></div>
```

Here is my dropbox folder for the website
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/n21lwdnr0mathgi/AACXVNAHBwEcJ9Skl24yjk0Aa

Comment: It might be nice if you created a CodePen for this so that we could reproduce the issue.

Comment: Use http://jsfiddle.com to demo your code for debugging.

Comment: Added a dropbox link to website

Comment: "None of them work for me..." Seems like you have bigger problems, then. This isn't a Lightbox issue.

Answer (score 3):

You are not suppose to load the jquery, lightbox and so on in the `<head>`. You are suppose to load it in the bottom of your code, before the closing of your `</body>` tag.

You can see Bootstrap Example here:
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/
See "Basic Example".

Comment: Thank you, this didn't solve my issue but I think it definitely helped.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by taking out the dropotron script, as they were competing somehow. Then, I moved the scripts to the bottom of the body tag. I should mention that the lightbox I used above STILL didn't work, but fancy box did.

Answer (score 0):

Your mileage may vary but if have a ton of other JS files and believe there's a conflict (here's a last-ditch measure) **remove the HTML and add it back again with jquery**. As for why this works it removes all the other event listeners and stops them from interfering. As for why it's doesn't remove the lightbox listeners I'm not sure.

```js
let original = $('#gallery').html();
$(item).html(original);
```